# DOORS DXL: insert OLE Object into any object attribute

Tags: ibm-doors

Is there a way to insert, with a DXL script, a word document as an OLE Object into any object attribute different from *Object Text*?

DXL function `oleInsert` allows to do it, but works only for attribute *Object Text*.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way I can see to do it directly but this is a good work around if your object text doesn't already have an OLE in it.

```
Object o = current
string filename = "PATH_TO_FILE"
oleInsert(o, filename, true)

string err = null

if (oleIsObject o){
  if (oleCut o){
    err = olePasteSpecial(o."OTHER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME", true)
    if(!null err)
      print err
  } else {
    print "Problem trying to cut object\n"
  }
} else {
  print "Does not contain an embedded object in its object text\n"
}
```

The `true` in `oleInsert` and `olePasteSpecial` are to insert the OLE as an icon. If you don't want it as an icon you can change them both to false.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you Steve, that is what a consultant recommended to me too.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: With DOORS 9.5 the signature of `oleInsert()` changed:

```
bool oleInsert(Object o,[attrRef],string fileName,[bool insertAsIcon])
```

With the documentation

> If the optional parameter *attrRef* is specified, then the OLE object is
>   embedded in the user-defined text attribute. If no parameter is
>   specified, then the OLE object is embedded in the system "Object Text"
>   attribute.

This makes it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Twonky! That's too helpful to me.
Additionally I added a sample code from dxl reference manual.

```
/*
this code segment embeds an existing word document into the current formal 
object
*/
string docName = "c:\\docs\\details.doc"
Object obj = current
if (oleInsert(obj, obj."my_text", docName)){
    print "Successfully embedded document\n"
} else {
    print "Problem trying to embed document\n"
}
```